# Exact value search with PHP

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to search the generated table and filter data. My problem is that when I search for lets say `1`, it doesn't search & filter only `1` but also the data containing `1` like `11, 21, etc.` .

How can I make it search and filter the exact data I enter?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbstats` WHERE CONCAT(`date`, `mode`, `svar`, `sdev`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

}
 else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbstats`";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}


function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbstats");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stats</title>
        <style>
            table,tr,th,td
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="stats_filter.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Mode</th>
                    <th>Svar</th>
                    <th>Sdev</th>
                </tr>


                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['mode'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['svar'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['sdev'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you concat all your columns to a single string and then search for an occurance of your search string anywhere in this concatenated string.

What you might actually want is to match each column exactly against your search string and return every row, which has an exact match in any column. To do an exact match, don't use `LIKE`. A simple `=` is what you want. To combine them, simply use the `OR` operator.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbstats WHERE
    date = '" . $valueToSearch . "' OR
    mode = '" . $valueToSearch . "' OR
    svar = '" . $valueToSearch . "' OR
    sdev = '" . $valueToSearch . "'";
```

On top of that, you should realy escape your input or even better, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 9):

When you do `LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'` you search for value that contain `%value%`.

If you want to search for value that start with your valueToSearch use `LIKE '".$valueToSearch."%'`, for value that end with your valueToSearch use `LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."'` and for exact value use `= '".$valueToSearch."'`.

So in your case just replace `LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'` by `= '".$valueToSearch."'`

**Edit :**

In your case, you are doing some `CONCAT` so I guess you want to find the exact value in one of your field, right?

If yes, try to replace :

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM `tbstats` 
          WHERE CONCAT(`date`, `mode`, `svar`, `sdev`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
```

by

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM `tbstats` 
          WHERE `date` = '".$valueToSearch."'
             OR `mode` = '".$valueToSearch."'
             OR `svar` = '".$valueToSearch."'
             OR `sdev` = '".$valueToSearch."'";
```

This way you will return data only if your exact searchValue is present inside one or your four field

Comment: Not sure if the simple replacement works, as he does some concatenations.

Comment: ok, I did what you said like `$query = "SELECT * FROM `tbstats` WHERE CONCAT(`date`, `mode`, `svar`, `sdev`) LIKE '".$valueToSearch."';` but now it doesn't show any results.

Comment: @Jason I made an edit because Philipp comment was right : you made a concat so you search a term inside a big string...so it return nothing. If you want the exact term to be present, I think you should made a `WHERE` condition where you test each field for the value.

Comment: Thanks Mickael, I got some errors, I tried philip's solution.

Comment: Yeah I forgot one `"` at the end ! I still get the exact same thing so my anwser is still good, but he see the "concat" thing first so good anwser is for him !

Comment: I was almost finished writing my answer after my comment, when I saw you updated your question and thought, it would be mad to throw my writings away.. nevertheless - gave you an upvote for your good answer!

Comment: @Jason I really hope, you noticed my comment about escaping and prepared statement - your solution is wide open to sql injections!

Comment: @Philipp np you saw the concat problem first :)

Comment: Thanks, Philipp, I'll do necessary changes.